# alignment of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment

I have several plots which I create with tikzpicture. The plot dimension is
set to `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\textwidth]`.
I try to align these plots right with `\begin{flushright}` and `\end{flushright}` but it shows no effect on the alignment.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{flushright}
   \input{gfx/1} \\
   \input{gfx/2} \\
   \input{gfx/3} \\
   \input{gfx/4} \\
\end{flushright}
\end{figure}
```

What can I do to have a clean right alignment of these 4 plots?

[image: four plots misaligned]

**EDIT:**
While I created the MWE I noted that this behaviour is caused by the setting `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}`. My solution is to abandon this command.

Comment: it would be great to see a complete minimum working example.... have you tried the key `scale only axis`?

Comment: The alignment problem you're having may be due to spurious spaces left in your code. Until you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), there is little we can do.

Comment: it is most probably due to the different vertical scales on each figure (1000 versus -5 for instance)

Comment: How do you create these plots? `pgfplots`? Only TikZ? The information `x=\textwidth` doesn't help much, you could still use a *x* coordinate greater than 1. If you use `pgfplots` the `x` key does not do anything. The `tikzscale` package helps with including a `pgfplots` plot with the right width. Maybe even a `groupplot` solution should be used. Without a MWE we can only guess which of the thousand possible ways to create these four plots you have used.

Answer (score 5):

The `flushright` environment can not affect the position of a box that is already `\textwidth` wide. `flushright` `flushleft` and `center` adjust the glue to position smaller boxes within the line but since this box is full width there is no adjustment possible.

`tikz` appears to be adjusting the position of the rotated label depending on the width of the numbers along that axis, which means that the visual effect is that there is no alignment.

What you want to do I suspect is not scale the `tizpicture` to `\textwidth` but instead specify the size of the actual plot axis, allowing the figure as a whole to vary in size according to the label position. Then set these varying size tikzpictures flush right.

Unfortunately I don't know any `tikz` so can't tell you what key incantation to use.